# Fullcalendar MySQL Insert not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, fullcalendar

Since all *"Fullcalendar"* guides out there are out of date(from the 1st version), I don't know how to `INSERT` or `SELECT` my Events into an out of my `MySQL` database.

AJAX for the `INSERT` :

```
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
   select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                    //var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
                    if (title) {
                        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'add_events.php',
                            data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function (json) {
                                alert('Added Successfully');
                            }
                        });
                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                {
                                    title: title,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end,
                                    allDay: allDay
                                },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                                );
                    }
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                },
```

add_event.php:

```
    <?php
// Values received via ajax
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

// connection to the database
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fullcalendar', 'ymartins', '');
} catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

// insert the records
$sql = "INSERT INTO evenement (title, start, end) VALUES (:title, :start, :end )";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end));
?>
```

Error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'formatDate'
```

I never used AJAX before, so if you have an awnser could you please explain it to me step by step. That would be kind of you.

### EDIT

my links

```
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lang/de.js'></script>
```

Comment: Your problem is, that you don't even get to PHP , this is clear Javascript error, probably missing Fullcalendar library ? :-)

Comment: I just downloaded the last version.

Comment: And is it included in code ? , As error says, that it is not there

Comment: Just edited my post :)

Comment: But is it possible to drag an event into the calendar and right after run the query ?

Comment: Maybe thats because the `$.fullcalendar.formatDate` is not available in the v2 of the fullcalendar, in the docs you can't find the formatdate method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$fullCalendar.formatDate` is **not supported anymore** in the **Version2**.

Now we use `.format()` instead of `.formatDate()`.

For more information about **upgrades**: http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/

Comment: In addition, fullcalendar uses moment.js objects for it's dates. So this is the API you should look at for date formatting: http://momentjs.com/docs/